# Is there a way to limit the maximum size of a websocket message?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have an application in which I wish to limit the maximum size of a message that was sent across the wire by a connected client. Since the theoretical [maximum of a message in Node.js is about 1.9 GB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24154610/1254837), I actually never want my application to allocate that big a chunk of memory if some malicious clients tries to send an over-sized packet.

How can I limit the **incoming** message size, to say, 1024 bytes?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977719/how-much-data-can-i-send-through-a-socket-emit

Comment: @jfriend00 my issue more related to memory allocation than bandwidth issue though. If we use `.length` on a string, if that string is 2gb... That's where we have the issue and when the memory starts to allocate towards checking the length.. :(  That guy's answer is 100% wrong, you're supposed to check the length first and close the clients connection if it exceeds.. not just rely on bandwidth. If you do that, that data will be sent to everyone that is connected (as that's a chat room he's talking about).

Comment: This question originates from https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/513. Now with reproduction/issue illustration. This is quite a big deal TBH.

Comment: You could pipe the incoming data to a file. Then check the size of the file at a certain interval/frequency.

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_buffersize

Comment: I don't think you can reliably inplement a solution to this at the application level. Maybe further down the stack.

Comment: @NiCkNewman : Did you ever find a solution to this (limiting message size BEFORE the entire message has been transferred over the wire and read into a block of memory)?

Comment: Was there ever an answer for this? I'd like to implement this lower in the stack but I don't know how.

Answer (score 8):

To anyone looking for answer to this question in future, use `maxPayload` option in server configuration to limit the message size before it is read by Node (which is almost always what you want)

```
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
        clientTracking: true,
        maxPayload: 128 * 1024, // 128 KB
        path: "/learn",
        //....
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Each character is 1 to 3 bytes in length. So you can technically just substring the string to get desired length.

```
var limited = fullString.substring(0, 1024);
```

Or you can use a package like this : [utf8-binary-cutter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8-binary-cutter)

Comment: I realized i didn't actually answer the question of 'where' to limit the size of string in socket.io pipeline. But i will leave the answer as it is since people looking for 'how to limit string' might end up here.

Comment: Just pointing out that every character in the string is not limited to 1 byte.
This char ☃ has a length of 3 bytes for example.