# Is there a way to know how much size a socket.io totally send and recv?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have searched the internet but not find any helping thing, and the document's of Socket.io also not mention it.

Comment: [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977719/how-much-data-can-i-send-through-a-socket-emit) may relates to your question.